# Add Multiple columns to dataframe scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a condition where I have to add 100 columns (to an existing DF)

The existing DF is like this

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
```

The 100 columns should be added after `c2` so the output looks likes this

```
c1 c2 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 ...... c100 c3 c4
```

I used the `.withColumn` to add the columns and arrange them in order using `.select`

Is there a better way to do this?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean by better? More readable? More performant?

Comment: There is not enough information in question to answer. can you show us what do you want to achieve, what is this column contains, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 5):

Use select.  The `withColumn` approach gets less efficient with a lot of columns.

```scala
val midCols: Seq[Column] = ...
df.select(Seq(c1, c2) ++ midCols ++ Seq(c3, c4):_*)
```

That way the new version of the Dataset is created in a single transformation.

Good info for others reading this is that you can use that pattern to construct and add complex column expressions.

```scala
val colsToAdd: Seq[Column] = Seq('a * 2 as "next_a", split('b) as "b_arr")
```

Given the naming/alias is within the definitions already, when you select them, they will have the intended name.  That way you don't have to deal with a rename after.